# Eclipse keybinding for opening the current class in the package explorer

Tags: eclipse

I have recently moved from Eclipse 3.4 to 3.5.  In 3.4 I had a key binding that allowed me to open the currently open class in the package explorer.  So for example, I would hit alt-F1 and the class in the editor would be shown in the package explorer pane.  I know I can click the "Link with Editor" button (looks like a left and right arrow on top of one another) in the package explorer pane but that would cause the package explorer to continuously update as I switch between classes in the editor.  I want the ability to open the chosen class in the package explorer when I decide to using a particular key binding.

In 3.4, I bound the alt-F1 key binding to the command called "Show in Package Explorer".  3.5 does not seem to have this command.

**Edit:** This issue seems to be caused by the importing of key bindings from 3.4 when a binding maps to a command that no longer exists in Eclipse 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the issue of importing 3.4 key bindings to 3.5 where there was a binding that no longer existed in 3.5, I had to re-export the 3.4 key preferences and manually open up the .epf file and remove the ALT+F1 mapping and then re-import into 3.5 which then allowed me to map ALT+F1 to the new 3.5 command.

Answer (score 3):

There is a command "**Show In (Show In Target Id: Package Explorer)**"

[screenshot http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/9939/screen1x.png](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/9939/screen1x.png)

Comment: I think that'll be the answer however when I tried that prior to posting this question I had the "When" set to "In Windows" like you have.  However when I hit alt-F1, it doesn't do anything except show an empty beige coloured box in the bottom right as though I had to choose between different commands.  If I change the "When" to "Editing Java Source", the alt-F1 shortcut works straight away.  I also noticed that it says I have an Alt-F1 conflict with an undefined command which is probably causing my problem - any ideas how to get rid of that conflict when it doesn't seem to match any command?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it might be because I imported my key preference from 3.4 to 3.5 and therefore it tried to match alt-F1 against a no longer existing command....might require a manual removal of a line from a file somewhere